# Matlab position list to velocity vector

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix of positions with column 1 as the x and column 2 as the y. I want to calculate the speed and orientation. I wrote this code

```
v=sqrt(diff(position(:,1)).^2 + diff(position(:,2)).^2);
theta=atan(diff(position(:,1))./diff(position(:,2)));
```

v seems to be right but theta is between -pi/2 and pi/2  but my nodes are moving in 360 directions... what am I doing wrong there?

Comment: Are you sure you need `atan(Vx/Vy)` and not `atan(Vy/Vx)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `atan2` instead of `atan`:

`P = atan2(Y,X)` returns an array P the same size as X and Y containing the element-by-element, four-quadrant inverse tangent (arctangent) of the real parts of Y and X. Any imaginary parts of the inputs are ignored. Elements of P lie in the closed interval [-pi,pi], where pi is the MATLAB floating-point representation of π.

Also I'd rather calculate `Vx` and `Vy` and store them in variables for later use and cleaner code:

```
vx = diff(position(:,1));
vy = diff(position(:,2));
v  = sqrt( vx.^2 + vy.^2 );
theta = atan2( vy , vx ); % note the order of vx and vy for atan2 function
```

Comment: theta= atan2(diff(position(:,1)),diff(position(:,2))) ?